# Why 5 bits are most often 0?

Tags: assembly, mips, bit, machine-code

I study MIPS and I see that 5 bits of the instruction is always 0 if the instruction is not a shift instruction. This seems like waste of resources and must it be done to enforce the simplicity of the regularity that all instreuctions have same length? Why can't shift instruction be 5 bits longer and the rest of the instructions use the bits to handle more overflow?

Comment: 5 bits longer instructions would require a bit-addressed architecture.

Comment: Also, it would not be so easy if most instructions were 32 - 5 = 27 bits. Implementing instruction fetches in HW would be hard and/or memory modules would have to be quite exotic.

Comment: They don't even need 5 more bits, shift immediate only uses two register fields so they could have re-used the remaining one for the count. But the I format can't really miss 5 bits, and anyway 27 bits is a silly width.

Comment: The field is used to encode the destination register in floating-point operations. Some floating-point ops need all four 5-bit fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When MIPS processor came out in the 80s, it was among the first so-called RISC processor, and this was a revolutionary concept. Most processors of the time (8080 series, 8086 series, Z80, 6502, 6800) were aiming at efficient instruciton coding, having instructions of variable length (they could take, 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes for example). This providing good code density, however, the decoding of the instructions and execution was a state machine, the amount of states depended on the exact instructions.

In order to perform faster, MIPS processors had revolutionary changes :

- All instructions are stored in a 32-bit word
- Instructions are extremely simple to decode, most bits should map directly to the hardware
- All instructions takes the same amount of "states" to execute
- The "states" were implemented in a pipeline rather than in a state machine, meaning that the instruction throughput is 1 cycle per instruction instead of N (actually there is N instructions simultaneously in the pipeline)

The first two points is why code density is low. **MIPS purposely makes program takes a lot more ROM/RAM space than they should, in order to be more efficient at executing them.**

Finally ARM did something that can be considered "best of both" : It is possible to switch between THUMB (higher code density, lower performance) and ARM (higher performance, lower code density, but still much better than what MIPS did) depending on the specific needs of each routine. This is probably why ARM is so popular and omnipresent.

Comment: Newer MIPS processors can implement MIPS16 or MicroMIPS extensions to the instruction set which give THUMB-like code compression.

Comment: @markgz Oh I wasn't even aware. Thanks for informing me! It's sad but MIPS architecture is not that much used anymore these days :(